# Laravel - Create new user with an existing row data

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent

What I am trying to achieve: A User needs to submit a form. The record will be stored in "trails" table. When the admin accepts the request, a user account will automatically be created with the form data stored in "trails" table.
[image]

I can change the value of the status with a toggle switch button. But I'm struggling to pass the data to create a new user using it. I have tried to use JQuery to pass the data but it didn't help so much.

Jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('.js-switch').change(function () {
    let status = $(this).prop('checked') === true ? 1 : 0;
    let trailId = $(this).data('id');
    let airName = $(this).data('air_name');
    let airAddress = $(this).data('address');
    let firstName = $(this).data('first_name');
    let lastName = $(this).data('last_name');
    let airEmail = $(this).data('email');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '{{ route('update.status') }}',
        data: {'status': status, 'trail_id': trailId,'air_name': airName,'address': airAddress,'first_name': firstName,'last_name': lastName,
        'email': airEmail},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.message);
        }
    });
});
});
```

controller:

```
public function updateStatus(Request $request)
{ 

$trail = Trail::findOrFail($request->trail_id);
$trail->status = $request->status;
$trail->save();


$user = new User;
$user->name = $request->first_name.' '.$request->last_name;
$user->email = $request->email;
$user->password = Hash::make('query123');
$user->save();


return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: I don't think you need jquery at all. If all the data is already in your `Trails` model, just pull all of the fields from there rather than from `$request`. Also, make sure those fields are `fillable` in your `Users` model.

Comment: How can I pull all the fields?

Comment: I'm guessing you already have them from your `findOrFail` call. `$trail->first_name` or whatever your field name is.